# Redirect from unavailable resource in Tomcat

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, redirect, tomcat7

I develop a web application on Apache Tomcat (Version 7) using JSF2. End users will probably fidget around with the address bar of a web application. I want to impose a default behavior on cases when users either call for a subpage that does not exist (which normally leads to a Tomcat file-not-found page (`"The requested resource () is not available."`) or call the application without specifying a startpage (like `http://localhost:8080/App/`). My desired behavior would be to redirect the user to a custom page with more telling information than a default server error message.

I have not figured out an available link between my JSF application and Tomcat. I tried to solve this problem using a Phase Listener, but it does not work - as no page associated with my application is requested. How to achieve this in the aforementioned technological environment?

Comment: did any of our answers solve your problem? if so, please be so kind and mark the correct answer! ;)

Comment: @donneo: according to the OP's question history he already know how things works here.

Comment: Confirmed, I do :) Still I'm not permanently logged in to SO, so there will be some time lag between posing a question and handling the incoming answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify your own errorpages in the deployment descriptor (web.xml):

[Errorpages in web.xml](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.servlet.http/webxmlerrorpagewithexceptiontype.htm)

You can even define Exception-specific error pages, i.e. if you want to display an error-page for the infamous ViewExpiredException.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It got 'accepted answer' for going a bit more into detail than BalusC's answer with the link.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the location of a custom HTTP 404 error page in `web.xml`.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorpages/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Quick and helpful as usual. Thank you!